# What is the reference point of the angles in 3d Extrude & Bevel in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've created a cube from a 4mm x 4mm square, extrude depth 4mm.

I need to rotate it fit a particular set of lines to create a pyramid (and other shapes). In the image below you I want to create the red cubes along the black lines.

[image]

I tried various entries into the dialogue boxes in the 3D Bevel and Extrude to no avail.

[image]

From which reference point and what exactly is being rotated per each dialogue box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool.

Illustrator's 3D Effect is object-isolated not global. Meaning each object is rotated/extruded from it's local center. There are no "scene" options in Illustrator's 3D effect.

If you need a 3d "scene" use a real 3D application.

Comment: I cannot spend time learning a 3d software to carry out this task, which I could do manually, albiet tediously. This seems to be the closest thing I can use to achieve what I need with some level of automation, if I just understood how it worked I could suss it out.

Comment: It works based upon the object itself. The rotation center is the center of the object. **Nothing** correlates or is related to *anything* else.

Comment: @AasimAzam it takes less time to learn a 3D application. I mean i know how it works and its still less work to draw it by hand than try to calculate the values. the reference point is center of object.